# Upload XML file by Web Service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-serialization

I am trying to upload a XML file from my local drive through SOAP web service, and it is saved into SQL 2008 R2 database. The data type of the column is xml. Below is the XML in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<DATARESULT>
   -<UNIT>
       <SERIALNO>359815604755374</SERIALNO>
       <SAVEDTIME>20130723113546</SAVEDTIME>
       <RESULT>PASS</RESULT>
       <MESSAGE/>
   </UNIT>
</DATARESULT>
```

I need to save the XML file as it is into SQL database. It is because I have to submit the XML file to our customer as a reference.

What method should I use in order to achieve that goal? 
Can I use XML serialization and deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would design the web method to accept a string of XML text. Then you can use this string directly in a SQL INSERT command.

```
public string UploadXml(string xmlString) {
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString)) {
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
      command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (xmlColumn) VALUES (@xmlText)";
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmlText", xmlString);
      // etc.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would have upvoted except that  you used an ASMX service in your example, making it a "bad example".